# Impossible to fix invalid token for me - where is the error?

Tags: node.js

I keep getting a [TOKEN_INVALID] after I fixed all my selfbot. This is the error:

```
(node:22476) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\yeet\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:135:26)
    at Client.login (C:\Users\yeet\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:221:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
(node:22476) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22476) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

OK, so here is the code another time:

```
const discord = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs");
const clc = require("cli-color");
const ConsoleTitle = require("node-bash-title");

const bot = new discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})

ConsoleTitle("TypicSelfBot version b1.0.0")

bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(clc.red("Your current name is: ${bot.user.username}"))
    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(clc.green("Ready to use"))
        console.log(clc.green("Prefix is -"))
        console.log(clc.green("Commands: -embed; More coming soon"))
    }, 200)
})
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content === "-embed")
    {
        let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription("Made by TypicScripter on Roblox, Discord: Typic#0001 or TypicScripter#0001")
        .setFooter("This is a embed message - adding arguments soon")
    }
})

bot.login("") // Put your Discord token here. This won't log your token.
```

Comment: Just fyi, selfbots are forbidden according to Discord's TOS

Comment: Do you see on the last line where it currently calls `bot.login` with an empty string and has a comment that says "put your discord token here" ?  Try putting your Discord token there in place of the empty string.

Comment: i did @ottomeister but i didnt wanted to put my token here

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a modified version of discord.js, it won't work, though I found that Discord has made selfbots impossible (they are also against their terms of service).

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with that also but the following fixed it. You have to navigate to the bot section under the developers portal and copy the token from there.